# style for color coded combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, datatrigger

I'm trying add data triggers to the default combobox style so each text item in the drop down box will be assigned a different color, and the selected item will be that color too.  I have successfully been able to color code the text column items in my datagrid by using this xaml code:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn ...>
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellSyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="Accepted">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But I cannot figure out how to do this for the combobox.  Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb01">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
          <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"
                                 Value="Accepted">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```